# proof of one sided limit comparison test and its converse

Tags: convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

I've seen limit comparison test to be used many times, but there exist a version of this test named '' one 
sided limit comparison test" which states:

> If $a_{n},b_{n}\ge0$ for all $n$ and $\limsup _{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}=c$ where $c$ is a finite 
>   nonnegative real number, then if $\sum_{n}^{ }b_{n}$ is convergent then so is $\sum_{n}^{ }a_{n}$.

The converse of this statement is as follows :

> If $a_{n},b_{n}\ge0$ for all $n$ and if $\sum_{n}^{ }a_{n}$ diverges but $\sum_{n}^{ }b_{n}$ converges, 
>   then necessarily $\limsup _{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}=\infty$
>   or equivalently $\liminf _{n\to\infty}\frac{b_{n}}{a_{n}}=0$

I've never seen any proof about these two statements, can someone give me a link or a proof?

Answer (score 0):

For the first question: $\frac {a_n} {b_n}$ is bounded, say by $M$  and this implies that $\sum a_n \leq M \sum b_n <\infty$.

For the second question: Suppose $\sum a_n$ diverges and $\sum b_n$ converges. Let us prove by contradiction that $\lim \sup \frac {a_n} {b_n} =\infty$. If $\lim \sup \frac {a_n} {b_n} <\infty$ then there exist $M$ and $n_0$ such that $\frac {a_n} {b_n} <M$ for all $n >n_0$. Since $\sum b_n <\infty$ and $a_n<M b_n$ for all $n >n_0$ it follows that $\sum a_n <\infty$ which is a contradiction. Hence $\lim \sup \frac {a_n} {b_n} $ must be $\infty$.

Comment: but I saw that here :https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test

Comment: @Allawonder Thank  you very much. Indeed I read limsup as limit. It was silly of me. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: @Absurd Sorry, my previous answer was wrong. I read the question wrongly. I have posted a revised answer now.

Comment: I read until you say, *'...which is a contradiction.'*  Why is it a contradiction, for if I've not missed anything significant then you've just provided a proof for the first highlighted sentence in OP.

Comment: @Allawonder The first part is found everywhere (in  books , on the net etc  etc) so I assumed that OP  really wanted an answer for second part. That is what I had proved. Now I have separated the two results.

Comment: @KaboMurphy In fact your two paragraphs above both prove the same thing -- the first part. And now after having looked at the second highlighted sentence above, I see that although OP mistakenly called it the *converse* of the first, what they actually wrote is the *contrapositive* to the first, so that both are actually equivalent.

Comment: @Kabo Murphy, Thanks I got it , but why we are allowed to have $b_n$ greater than or " equils " to $0$? I just think since $b_n$ is in the denominator so it cannot be zero

Comment: @Absurd Strictly speaking we should not have $0$ in the denominator.  But if you interpret $a_n /b_n$ as $\infty$ whenever $b_n =0$ and $a_n >0$ my proof works fine.